# UIImagePNGRepresentation loses its transparency

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am working on an app that connects multiple devices using the networking protocol UPnP.

Among others, I can exchange images and they are files stored inside a folder in my project folder.

For sending the images I am given predefined methods.

```
if let imageRequested = UIImage(named:"logo.png"){

    let fileType = "image/png"
    let pngRepresentation = [UInt8](UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageRequested)!)
    let fileSize = UInt32(pngRepresentation.count)

    writeBegin!(aWriterData, fileSize, fileType)
    aWriteResource!(aWriterData, pngRepresentation, fileSize)
    aWriteEnd!(aWriterData)

}
```

However, the receiver gets the image with black background when it is transparent. I know It is not a receiver issue because there is an Android version that sends the same images and they are received with transparency.

any ideas why?

Comment: What are you using to send the data? Maybe something below encodes the image in jpg when sending it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImageJPEGRepresentation will convert the resulting image into a JPEG, which doesn't support transparency. Are you sure that you use UIImagePNGRepresentation, not UIImageJPEGRepresentation?

If you use UIImagePNGRepresentation - it's strange, it should work fine, could you provide more details?

Comment: Correct, but OP is using UIImagePNGRepresentation and not UIImageJPEGRepresentation. UIImagePNGRepresentation should keep the transparency.

Comment: Yes. I doesn't happen when the image is inside a xcasset. Any Ideas why it does happen when the file is not declared in the xcasset